# How to get list value and add new column from list value in data frame using R Algorithm

Tags: r, algorithm

I'm basically .net developer one of my project page needs data from MongoDB collection. But I need to compare each column value so I used R language. I have retrieved data from MongoDB but some of columns have a list of variables so I'm not able to compare each column. Can you help me to separate the values of the list column and add a new column with the same name of list variable?

If its possible to use any algorithm to solve means it's more preferable.

**My sample Data frame(Data set)**

```
ID  UserDetails                                                                                                                                                                    CompanyDetails    

1   list(UserID = 247891,Useraltr="Admin",UsercumEmpdetaisl=list(list(FirstName="Jack",LastName="De")))                                                                     list(ComyAddress="4/8 9 Block UD",ComyReg="344/88 7 Cross UK")

2   list(UserID=c(247891,256134),Useraltr=c("Admin","SuperAdmin"),UsercumEmpdetaisl=list(list(FirstName=c("peter","jhon","Vector"),LastName =c("Anderson","VJ","PK"))))     list(ComyAddress =c("1BLOCK","2BLOCK"),ComyReg=c("1MainRoad","3street"),LandMark =c("Near post Office","check post"))
```

**Result data frame**

```
ID    UserID           Useraltr             FirstName               LastName             ComyAddress           ComyReg              LandMark

1     247891            Admin                Jack                    De                  4/8 9 Block UD    344/88 7 Cross UK        Empty(NULL)

2    247891,256134   Admin,SuperAdmin    peter,jhon,Vector        Anderson,VJ,PK        1BLOCK,2BLOCK     1MainRoad,3street        Near post Office,check post
```

data frame dput data for first 2 row.

```
structure(list(ID = c("1", "2"), UserDetails = list(structure(list(
    UserID = 247891, Useraltr = 'Admin', UsercumEmpdetaisl = list(structure(list(
        FirstName = "Jack", LastName ="De" ), .Names = c("FirstName", "LastName"
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("UserID", 
"Useraltr", "UsercumEmpdetaisl"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(UserID = c(247891,256134), Useraltr = c('Admin','SuperAdmin'), UsercumEmpdetaisl = list(
        structure(list(FirstName = c("peter", "jhon", "Vector"), LastName = c("Anderson", 
        "VJ","PK")), .Names = c("FirstName", "LastName"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("UserID", 
    "Useraltr", "UsercumEmpdetaisl"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
    CompanyDetails = list(structure(list(ComyAddress = "4/8 9 Block UD"
    , ComyReg = "344/88 7 Cross UK"), .Names = c("ComyAddress", "ComyReg"
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), structure(list(
        ComyAddress = c("1BLOCK","2BLOCK"), ComyReg = c("1MainRoad","3 street"
        ),LandMark=c("Near post Office","check post")), .Names = c("ComyAddress", "ComyReg","LandMark"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2))), .Names = c("ID", 
"UserDetails", "CompanyDetails"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @akrun,But my question is i need to done using algorithm.

Comment: @www, i have shared my mongodb r data frame returned data frame dput .correct me if i any where wrong.

Comment: can you please  help me to done my post.

Comment: Have you considered re-writing your mongo query to give you the data in the correct format, rather than doing a separate wrangling step in R?

Comment: @SymbolixAU,Thanks for your response,i'm using mongo query to get data from mongodb into data frame only I didn't change any format.i'm directly getting first two row of data from data frame . I used mongo quety is Test<-mongott$find() and mongolite to connect mongoDB.

Comment: I think it would be better to use an `aggregation` query, so when you get the data from Mongo it will already be in a tabular / data.frame format

Comment: @SymbolixAU,I used aggregation  query also but I'm getting same format Ex:Test<-mongott$aggregate().

Comment: You actually need to write a query

Comment: @SymbolixAU,sorry I don't get you,i'm using only one query to get data from mongoDB For Ex:Test<-mongott$aggregate().if I'm wrong guide me.

Comment: You need to research the mongodb aggregation framework. It defines how to write queries to filter, find, sort, search, etc, and handle complex nested JSON structures so you can un-nest them into simple tables